# Spark batch job in multiservices architecture

Tags: apache-spark, architecture, microservices

I"m trying to figure out how to design my service in a microservice architecture.
My service aim is to calculate aggregations, we are using Apache Spark batch jobs.

So I'm really interested to get your advice and some experience you get in similar cases.

Comment: Your question is a bit too unspecific. Let us know what you have researched so far about it and where your exact questions are. In case you haven't, here a starting point: https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html

Comment: My microservice(running inside k8s) should launch spark batch job for calculating aggregations, which are basically another services. my question is if do you think it's a valid architecture?